# ssh, Protocol major versions differ

Tags: linux, ssh

It worked when I use Mac OS X El Captain, but after I update to MacOS Sierra, it fails:

```
$ ssh -1 $IP
ssh1 is not supported
$ ssh -2 $IP
Protocol major versions differ: 2 vs. 1
```

So which version should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade your ssh client to version which supports version 2 of SSH protocol (or check is it enabled in ssh client configs).

You may also try `ssh -2` command to select version 2.

http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/protocol-major-versions-differ-1-vs-2/

> The error above normally comes up when you try to ssh into a machine which has it’s allowed ssh protocol versions locked down to a single version, today it’s normally version 2.
>
> Old days;
>
> ```
>  #Protocol 2,1
> ```
>
> Today;
>
> ```
>  #Protocol 2
> ```

According to wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Version_2.x, SSH-2 was adopted in 2006

> In 2006, a revised version of the protocol, SSH-2, was adopted as a standard. This version is incompatible with SSH-1. SSH-2 features both security and feature improvements over SSH-1. Better security, for example, comes through Diffie–Hellman key exchange and strong integrity checking via message authentication codes. ... Due to SSH-2's superiority and popularity over SSH-1, some implementations such as Lsh[21] and Dropbear[22] support only the SSH-2 protocol.